# Linear maps and matrix coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, definition

I am currently working through this page in my script:

[image: untitled]

Can somebody explain what this means and how it works in practice? Perhaps if I saw an example I could follow it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Image does not load.

Comment: @batman http://s28.postimg.org/5yhuzwu8r/Untitled.png

Comment: The image doesn't load, and linking to it isn't very effective as one has to look and come back, or open two windows: too cumbersome.

Comment: @donantonio different image uploaded, working?

Comment: @user127700 , now it's fine.

Comment: Could you please type your question? Image does not load.

Comment: @user2357, what are you having problems with *exactly*?

Comment: for me it did load just answering!

Comment: @DonAntonio sorry, it loads now.

Comment: I can see the question just fine, @user2357, yet it is too long and it isn't clear *what* precisely is your problem here...

Comment: I would love to answer but the way the OP, on [this other page](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/763491/6179), apparently silently downvoted the two answers posted and never answered the queries for clarifications, is making me shy.

Answer (score 0):

#### What do we gain from this

Basically for a linear map $T$ it is enought to see what happens with a basis (like $\{e_1,e_2\})$ of $V$ under the linear map $T$ to know what it is doing with any vector and vice versa.

This way we can easily define coordinate transforms used for a lot of things. And it does gives us a matrix for any linear map, between two vector spaces $V,W$ and their basises $\mathcal{B}_V,\mathcal{B}_W$, because sometimes you don't have vector spaces that are so simple as $\mathbb{R}^n$.

There are these diagrams which show this behaviour:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
V @>{T}>> W\\
@A{\phi}AA @A{\psi}AA \\
K^n@>{L}>> K^n
\end{CD}
$$